# Can i access the child's of included layout directly by findViewById() method in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can i access the  Child's of included layout that included the main activity layout, directly by `findViewById()` method in main activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah this way.

```
//in XML 
    <include layout="@layout/extLayout" 
    android:id="@+id/myLayout" />

//in Activity 
    View view= findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    Button button= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: Thanks. But when  i use findViewById() method to find included layout child's directly in activity that is working correctly.Is this a risk?

Comment: As include are not real view but rather are the instructions, it may throw Null Pointer Exception. So its safe to add the id to the include layout and use it.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can access that included layout in  activity layout using `findValueById()`

Comment: can i access the child's of included layout directly?

Comment: thank for your answer. But the copmlete and perfect answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055955/7766540

Comment: no need to get particular View you can directly access using the main layout. try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally access child by findViewById. When you include one layout in other layout, it's same when you code inside.

Comment: thank for your answer. But the copmlete and perfect answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055955/7766540

Comment: okay i c. it's same, but it's more  clearly. Btw, good luck ^_^